# How to send multiple values in rest url in java

Tags: java, rest, get, restful-url

I have a get request like below.

Https://localhost.com:8080/search?date=2021110

I get the result when I make a get request. But my requirement is to get multiple values with 2 status. Like status=2 and status=3
If I modify my url like this

Https://localhost.com:8080/search?status=2&status=3&date=2021110

Comment: You can not put same `query string` in `url` because it create ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the request method to POST. Or you can also use ',' between two values and handle it on server programming.